# Importing all files from folder and putting them into an array with webpack require.context

Tags: javascript, webpack, directory

So I looked at the docs for webpack, and I'm pretty sure that `require.context` is what I need to put all my images from a folder in an array.

In the folder "Perruet" I've got three jpg images.

By doing exactly what the doc say:

```
const cache = {};

function importAll(r) {
    
  r.keys().forEach((key) => (cache[key] = r(key)));

}

importAll(require.context('./img/Perruet', false, /\.jpg$/));


console.log("photo", cache)
```

The console.log give me this result:
[image]

What I need is the "default" value of the image that would give me the path to my image, but I can't get this value. Can someone help me to retrieve this value?

Comment: Hey, here is the webpack documentation i used : https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext

Answer (score 0):

```
    const cache1 = {

};

function importProjets(r) {

r.keys().forEach((key) => (cache1[key] = r(key)));

}

importProjets(require.context('./img/projets',true,/\.jpg$/));





console.log(cache1)
let vals1 = Object.values(cache1);
console.log(vals1);

let projectArray = [];
let projetsImg = [];
let empty=[];

export {projectArray};
function createArrayProjet(){
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++){

projetsImg.push(vals1[i].default)
}
projectArray.push(projetsImg);
console.log("projectArrayMiddle",projectArray);

projetsImg=empty;


for (let i = 20; i < vals1.length; i++){

projetsImg.push(vals1[i].default)
}
projectArray.push(projetsImg);


}



createArrayProjet();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).